# What is the easy way to create reusable widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: Text("Random Text",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Text("Owner",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Please take care that you format your code properly such that it is at least in a readable format.

Comment: Can you specify your question? You just posted a code example.. But whats your question/problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's an easy way. But for a simple reusable widget, you can place your widget inside a `StatelessWidget` or a `StatefulWidget`.

Here's the example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyReusableWidget('Nikola Tesla', 'Owner'), //Input the name and role variable when you call the widget
            MyReusableWidget('Albert Einstein', 'Developer'),
            MyReusableWidget('Isaac Newton', 'Technician'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyReusableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name; // provide a place for the input's data
  final String role;

  MyReusableWidget(this.name, this.role);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  name, // This is where you place your 'name' data
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  role, // This is where you place your 'role' data
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

I'm creating a widget called `MyReusableWidget`. I am gonna call that widget inside my `MyApp` 3 times. And then each widget should provide different names and roles.

So inside my `MyReusableWidget`, I provide two String data-types called `name` and `role` to *store* my data when I call the widget.

```
  final String name; // provide a place for the input's data
  final String role;

  MyReusableWidget(this.name, this.role);
```

And then I want to place my `name` and `role` variable inside a `Text` widget:

```
                child: Text(
                  name, // This is where you place your 'name' data
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                ),
```

and:

```
               child: Text(
                  role, // This is where you place your 'role' data
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
```

After that, inside my `MyApp` widget, I can call `MyReusableWidget` as much as I want and provide different `name` and `role` value on each widget.

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyReusableWidget('Nikola Tesla', 'Owner'), //Input the name and role variable when you call the widget
            MyReusableWidget('Albert Einstein', 'Developer'),
            MyReusableWidget('Isaac Newton', 'Technician'),
          ],
        ),
```

Result:

[image: Result]

And that's it.
You can store any kind of data-type on it (String, int, double, etc).

I hope it will be helpful.